# Zookeeper HA setup with hierarchical quorum (6 nodes)

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We are trying to setup a ZK cluster using 6-nodes (3+3 in 2 Data Centers). Our servers/VMs are provisioned in pairs across 2 Data Centers and the latency between the two DCs is less than 2-3 ms, so we think its ideal to use all 6 servers using hierarchical quorums rather than the typical 5 node setup. Also a stretched cluster (3+2 nodes in 2 Data Centers) may not tolerate the second data center failure.

We have used the reference architecture described in this article [Kafa Deployment Strategy](https://www.infoq.com/articles/resilient-kafka-goldman-sachs/)

Our current setup is as follows (Servers 1a, 2a and 3a are located in Data Center a :: Servers 1b, 2b and 3b are located in Data Center b).

### Servers

- server.**1**=1a:2888:3888
- server.**2**=1b:2888:3888
- server.**3**=2a:2888:3888
- server.**4**=2b:2888:3888
- server.**5**=3a:2888:3888
- server.**6**=3b:2888:3888

### Groups

- group.1= **1**:**2**:**3**
- group.2= **4**:**5**
- group.3= **6**

What is the ideal weight configuration that can withstand any one data center failure?

- weight.1 = 1
- weight.2 = 1
- weight.3 = 1
- weight.4 = 1
- weight.5 = 1
- weight.6 = 1

Comment: Never use an even number of Zookeepers. Add an extra in one of the data centers. And they all have equal weight, so why does it matter

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your response. Since our servers are provisioned in pairs, we always end up with even number of servers in 2 DCs. But even if I use a stretched cluster of 3 primary and 2 secondary nodes, if the primary Data Center goes down the ZK cluster would go down as there is no majority. You may notice from the link in my original post that Goldman Sachs team had the same problem and they ended up using all 6 nodes (across Primary and Secondary data centers)

Comment: Ultimately, you need at least 3 zones / datacenters, like the cloud offerings have.

Comment: In any case, what's wrong with equal weights? Is one datacenter less latent to your Zookeeper clients? Or are clients stretched across both DCs as well? (clients include Kafka)

Comment: Yes, in an ideal case we would have preferred to have 3 zones. But such setup isn't available yet in our organization. With equal weights, I suspect we may not have a majority within the group if one data center goes down (hence the quorum may not be formed). We may have to run some tests, but we are not sure about this yet.

Comment: What if you setup some programmatic monitoring to say "if other datacenter is offline, create a new local ZK"? Or just setup a local follower node, then edit its config to be a leader in such an event? That may allow you to have an odd number total

Comment: @rslack hierarchical quorums requires majority group. In your case, majority group is equal or greate than 2. So if data center a goes down, you still have 2 groups in data center b, it's still enough to form a quorum, on the other hand, if data center b goes down, the quorum can not be formed.